# Parametric differentiation for equation of a tangent.

Tags: real-analysis, parametric, curves

Given $y=t^3-\frac{5}{2}t^2$ and $x=\sqrt t$, for $t>0$,

a) Use parametric differentiation to express $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $t$ in simplified form.

b) Show that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=at^2+bt$, determining the constants $a$ and $b$.

c) Obtain an equation for the tangent to the curve which passes through the point of inflection.

Comment: I've found the first derivative, however the second derivative is not suitable for the form shown in part b).

Comment: Just need help with part b),.

Comment: Are you using the chain rule for the second derivative?

Comment: No.  You wouldn't use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you already have $$\frac {dy}{dx}=6t^{\frac 52}-10t^{\frac 32}$$
Then $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}$$
$$=30t^2-30t$$

Comment: how did you get $6t^\frac{3}{2}$ in the first derivative

Comment: That was a typo. Now fixed!

Comment: For part c) you would let $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$,since there's a point of inflection, and then find t.

Comment: ...then sub in the value of t, in the two equations

Comment: Yes, so $t=1$ at the inflexion

Comment: You're wlecome. If you are happy with the answer, you might want to accept the answer rather than leave it as unanswered.

Comment: Okay i will do, but what did you get as the value of the gradient  for part c).